# SQL select *, but override 'column value' of row if present in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

For simplicity let's say I have two tables with identical rows.

User with fields "id" and "name". And user_override with fields "id" and "name"

I want to run Select statement that will select all values from User and override any value if it is present in UserOverride

something like (obviously fails - COALESCE does not take au.* as argument)

```
SELECT COALESCE(uo.*, u.*) FROM USER u LEFT JOIN USER_OVERRIDE uo ON u.id = uo.id
```

and result would be something like

```
id | name
1  | 'normal name 1'
2  | 'overriden name 2'
3  | 'normal name 3
```

I would do it with simply overriding each value but it's going to be in function and I'd rather not change it every single time and just reuse the same query.

It is guaranteed that those two tables have same columns.

Is something like this possible? What would be the syntax?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: jarlh - the structure is simple, result is there, if needed you can derive the table data from result

Comment: instead of COALESCE(uo.*, u.*)  you have to put  COALESCE(uo.id, u.id) ,COALESCE(uo.name, u.name) for each field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you were close to the answer:

```
SELECT  u.id ,COALESCE(uo.Name, u.name) as name_New
FROM USER u 
LEFT JOIN USER_OVERRIDE uo ON u.id = uo.id
```

you just can't coalesce everything with one instruction.

That's because Coalesce ( check ref:[coalesce](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))

> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the
>   first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL

So you have to evaluate every single column **separately**

Comment: Well, that's the point. I need to COALESCE every single column in the table USER, so that it can be expanded whenever new row is added to both tables

Comment: So, in short, there is no way to make it extendable in SQL and you MUST always use coalesce on every column in table, right? Well, that's also anwer, if you could make it more obvious in your answer (like bold text) I would accept it...

Comment: dunno if i've added the information you need, let me know

Comment: I meant to say "override column value in row" with my question. It seems I made typo. Regardless, answer would be same - you have to override every value by hand, so your answer (with updates) should be the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Expressions only return a single value.  You *can* do:

```
select u.id, coalesce(uo.name, u.name) as name
from user u left join
     user_override uo
     on uo.id = u.id;
```

If all values are being overridden in any given row, you can do:

```
select uo.id, uo.name
from user_override uo
union all
select u.id, u.name
from user u
where not exists (select 1 from user u where u.id = uo.id);
```

Comment: first row is close, but I need it "dynamic"; your second query would add row if it does not exist in first table. I need to change value if inside row if it's not null in second table :) thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from both tables with different conditions and merge with `UNION`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name
FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.id = uo.id)
UNION 
SELECT uo.id, uo.name
FROM user_override uo
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.id = uo.id)
```